# Flutter - Search elements in array with firstwhere

Tags: dart, flutter

The problem is simple: What is the correct way to search element in array ?

My code is

```
data = [{id: 1, descripcion: Asier}, {id: 2, descripcion: Pepe}]
estateSelected= data.firstWhere((dropdown)=>dropdown.id==1);
```

The error that return is

> Bad state: no element

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have some errors, this should work:

```
  var data = [{'id': 1, 'descripcion': 'Asier'}, {'id': 2, 'descripcion': 'Pepe'}];
  var estateSelected = data.firstWhere((dropdown) => dropdown['id'] == 1);
  print(estateSelected);
```

Fastest way to try is on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)